# C - Very Strange Implicit Declaration

Tags: c, declaration, implicit

I had a function in a file "draw.h":

```
void TileSystem() {
    // Some code here.        
}
```

And in the "main.c" file, I call it, because I have #included "draw.h" in the file. The function works nicely well!!

But then, I decide to rename the function to

```
void CreateTileSystem() {
    // Some code here.        
}
```

And I get the following output:

```
gcc main.c -std=c99 -o main `pkg-config --cflags --libs allegro-5.0 allegro_acodec-5.0 allegro_audio-5.0 allegro_color-5.0 allegro_dialog-5.0 allegro_font-5.0 allegro_image-5.0 allegro_main-5.0 allegro_memfile-5.0 allegro_physfs-5.0 allegro_primitives-5.0 allegro_ttf-5.0`
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:217:12: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘CreateTileSystem’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
/tmp/cclNEg6q.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0xb1e): undefined reference to `CreateTileSystem'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

And then, I just rename it back to TileSystem and works well. I have no other references in the entire code. It makes no sense at all! I want to rename, in order to use verbs in functions (A more "correct" standard, I think). Well, I would really like to know what happens. I really CAN'T find errors, and the fact that when I rename it, it backs to work, frustrates me even more.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You should not be adding the function body in a header file, only add the signature, and put function body in a separate c/cpp file.

Comment: I call in this way TileSystem();, and works. And then, I call it in this way CreateTileSystem();, and it does not work.

Comment: It's possible somehow that the problem is with THE NAME? I don't know, some random memory issue, maybe... But I get the same result changing the function to int or float, etc.

Comment: My guess is that there is a redeclaration of TileSystem in main.c that is taking effect. Generate a preprocessed file to see what the compiler sees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to also change the name in the header file, `draw.h`.

That error/warning indicates that there was no forward declaration for the function, which in older C dialects results in an assumption that the function is `int fn(int)` (if memory serves).

It works when you change it back because the header was never modified, so it's still providing a forward declaration of the old name.

Comment: Just a nitpick; C99 did away with implicit int.

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating a couple of simple files like you've described here, but I don't get any problems.  So:

- are you sure you used the same name for the new function in both draw.h and main.c (really sure)?
- I don't know about allegro: does it happen to have a function called TileSystem in it?

Beyond those, I would recommend starting with a bare bones setup (so just the include, the main function, and the call in main.c, and just the declaration in draw.h), make sure that compiles with `gcc main.c -std=c99 -o main`, and then build your application up to what it is currently, piece by piece, until the error starts happening again.  That should help you identify the source of the problem.

Comment: I'll do just that, thank you! Yes, they have the exact same name, and there's no function in Allegro called "TileSystem". I get some interesting output when I try to call it in this way: extern CreateTileSystem();. When I do it, the output is different:

warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘CreateTileSystem’ [enabled by default]

For some reason, I think that the CreateTileSystem is not recognizing its type (It's ignoring the void, or something like that, and defaulting to int). Well, nothing is wrong with the names. I'll try to do what you've said to try to find the problem :).

Answer (score 0):

I recreated the header file, without altering anything, and it worked. It really had something to do with me never altering the file (I mean, renaming the file or excluding it). Some very underground compiling issue happened.